# How to edit the readonly field in Jmeter 5.2.1?

Tags: html, json, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have recorded a script for the help desk ticket and inside that ticket one field "operation" is read-only and it's dependent on other fields.

now, I want to fill the data in the "operation" field, but due to read-only validation and dependent on other fields, the script failed.

In addition, I already tried to pass values(false value replaced with value) via script but it failed. for example:

Search -> "prodid":false,
replace all -> with "prodid":123,

Kindly suggest how to pass values or ids in the read-only selection field.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [HTML readonly attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) - JMeter doesn't care about it, JMeter acts on [HTTP protocol level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP).

If you can follow your test steps using a real browser without issues and cannot using JMeter most probably your attempt to replay the script fails due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter), start from adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan and inspecting requests details for any dynamic values, if they are there - they're a subject to correlation, you will need to extract the values from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)(s) and replace recorded hard-coded values with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)(s) from the Post-Processor(s)

Comment: on recording time, I can not able to fill in data in the field because it's a read-only field. after recording, I reviewed a script and see the value is set to false. now I want to replace this false to the id like 123 or 565.

I already tried with CSV to pass a value but not working. @Dmitri

Comment: If you cannot amend the value using the real browser due to the system under test limitations you won't be able to do it with JMeter as well, [well-behaved JMeter test is supposed to produce the same network footprint as the real browser does](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser). If there are multiple data relationships you can query them from the database using [JDBC Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) but unfortunately I cannot help you with this because I don't know the app